# Create List of objects from dynamic form fields

Tags: javascript, java, spring, thymeleaf

I am working on a project with Java, Spring, Thymeleaf where I have a `form` with another `form` inside it. **Number of `input` fields of the inner `form` depends on the value of an `input` field from the outer `form`.** How can I create `List` of Objects from the inner `form` and then pass it when the outer `form` is submitted? Simplified and smaller version of my code is given below:

**FamilyInformationController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/family")
public class FamilyInformationController {
    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String add(Model theModel) {
        FamilyInformation theFamilyInformation = new FamilyInformation();
        theModel.addAttribute("theFamilyInformation", theFamilyInformation);
        return "family/family_add_form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("theFamilyInformation") FamilyInformation theFamilyInformation) {
        theFamilyInformation.setId((long) 0);
        familyInformationRepository.save(theFamilyInformation);
        return "redirect:/family/index";
    }
}
```

**FamilyInformation.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "family_information")
public class FamilyInformation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "fathers_name")
    private String fathersName;

    @Column(name = "mothers_name")
    private String mothersName;

    @Column(name = "spouse_name")
    private String spouseName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "familyInformation")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<ChildrenInformation> childrenInformation;

    public FamilyInformation() {

    }
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**ChildrenInformation.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "children_information")
public class ChildrenInformation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "date_of_birth")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "family_information_id", nullable = false)
    private FamilyInformation familyInformation;

    public ChildrenInformation() {

    }
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**family_add_form.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/family/create}" th:object="${theFamilyInformation}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right" for="fathersName">Father's Name</label>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fathersName" name="fathersName" placeholder="Enter Father's Name"
                        th:field="*{fathersName}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right" for="mothersName">Mother's Name</label>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mothersName" name="mothersName" placeholder="Enter Mother's Name"
                        th:field="*{mothersName}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right" for="spouseName">Spouse Name</label>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="spouseName" name="spouseName" placeholder="Enter Spouse Name"
                        th:field="*{spouseName}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Input field for number of children and input fields in the children information form -->
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right" for="childrenNumber">Number of Children</label>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6 row">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control col-6" id="childrenNumber" name="childrenNumber"
                        placeholder="Enter Number of Children">
                    <div class="col-1"></div>
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-light col-5" value="Enter Children Information" th:data-children-number="0"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#childrenInformationModal">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-5"></div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-space btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5"></div>
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- Children information form -->
        <div class="modal fade text-center" id="childrenInformationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
            aria-labelledby="childrenInformationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Children Information</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="childrenInformationForm"></form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#childrenInformationModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
            var numberOfChildreValue = $('#childrenNumber').val();
            var modal = $(this);
            var childrenInformationForm = modal.find('#childrenInformationForm');
            childrenInformationForm.empty();

            // row for each child consists three input field
            var row = '<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-4"><label class="col-form-label">Child\'s Name</label><input class="form-control" type="text"></div><div class="form-group col-4"><label class="col-form-label">Child\'s Gender</label><input class="form-control" type="text"></div><div class="form-group col-4"><label class="col-form-label">Child\'s Date Of Birth</label><input class="form-control" type="text"></div></div>';
            numberOfChildren = parseInt(numberOfChildreValue, 10);

            // add rows for each child
            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; i++) {
                childrenInformationForm.append(row);
            }
            var lastRow = '<div class="row"><div class="col-4"></div><div class="form-group col-4"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-space btn-primary">Submit</button></div><div class="col-4"></div></div>';
            childrenInformationForm.append(lastRow);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```